# Какой дистрибутив LINUX выбрать для маршрутизатора?

Tags: linux, сервер, администрирование, proxy, router

В маленьком офисе установлен роутер DIR-300. До сегодняшнего момента работал исправно, но появилось желание и необходимость сделать следующее:

1. Авторизация через AD
2. Фильтрация по URL с использованием групп AD
3. Счетчик трафика по пользователям
4. Просмотр статистики руководителем (отдельный web-интерфейс?)

ДАНО:

> Входящий канал - 100 МБит. Белый IP
>
> 50 компьютеров
>
> Системный блок 1024 RAM, 20 Gb HDD, 3GHz CPU

Какой дистрибутив linux лучше использовать для достижения цели?

**UPD:** Интересуют дистрибутивы, имеющие требуемый функционал "из коробки", очень хотелось бы, чтобы там был WEB интерфейс или любое другое GUI

Comment: Возможно не верно задал вопрос. Меня интересует максимально удобный в настройке, по возможности, чтобы указанный функционал присутствовал из коробки.

Comment: Обновил вопрос, чтобы было понятно...

Comment: это вопрос-перепись дистрибутивов линукса?

Comment: Это вопрос выбора дистрибутива под определенные задачи

Comment: @GrayHoax по поводу веб-интерфейса - посмотрите Webmin и аналоги

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть старое и работающее правило - "выбирай тот дистрибутив/ОС, который знает ближайший к тебе гуру!"

Если гуру нет, то выбираешь то, что лучше знаешь сам.

Если Linux не принципиален, то посмотри в сторону [pSense](https://www.pfsense.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, вас заинтересует проект [OpenWRT](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenWrt).

Есть даже [таблица](http://wiki.openwrt.org/ru/toh/start) поддерживаемых устройств

Answer (score 0):

UbuntuServer - [download](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server/thank-you?country=KZ&version=14.04.2&architecture=amd64) - но надо очень хорошо знать Linux - в этом дистребьютиве отсуствует графическая оболочка

Comment: А почему не FreeBSD?

Comment: @GrayHoax потому что вы попросили Linux. А FreeBSD - это не Linux!

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте готовый дистрибутив http://www.zentyal.org/ . Очень функциональный, из коробки работает много чего. Советую!